# dependency information for org.springframework.transaction in maven

Tags: spring, maven

Can you please give me the dependency information
for atrifactId org.springframework.transaction.
I searched the maven repositories,but the search yielded nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's because at least in Maven central there is no artifact with that artifact id. If you want the transaction framework of Spring, this has the artifact id `spring-tx`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

On http://search.maven.org/ you can also search with Java class names, if you're searching for an artifact, where you don't know the exact coordinates.